# What do I need for masking a UIImageView and how do I do it in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, mask

I was wondering what I would need if I wanted to use a mask image to get my `UIImageView` in a specific shape. From what I understand, to create a mask, I need to have an image with the shape of the mask all black on top of a white background. Something like this, for example:

[image: Star-shaped mask image]

First of all, is this sufficient to shape an image view, and if so, how do I do it in Swift 3? I can only find masking code that is either outdated or written in Objective-C. I've tried simply assigning the image above to an `UIImageView` and then assign the image view to the `mask` property of the `UIImageView` I want to shape, like so:

```
self.defaultImageView.mask = self.maskImageView
```

This didn't do anything. It just made `self.maskImageView` disappear (both image view's added through the storyboard and connected using `IBOutlet` properties). I'm sure I'm forgetting to do something. It can't be this simple. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out. Like I said, I put both image views on the exact same spot, on top of each other, in the storyboard.

**UPDATE:**
My first attempt to set the mask programmatically after deleting it from my storyboard.

```
let layer:CALayer = CALayer()
    let mask:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Black-Star-Photographic-Agency")!
    layer.contents = mask
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ((self.defaultImageView.image?.size.width)!), height: (self.defaultImageView.image?.size.height)!)
    self.defaultImageView.layer.mask = layer
    self.defaultImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The result was that the image view had completely disappeared and wasn't visible anymore. Am I doing something, am I forgetting something or both?

Comment: @matt So the only way is to create one on my own? That's gonna be tricky because I have some very complicated shapes I need to turn into masks.

Comment: @matt Oh, well you said "opaque and transparent", but you're gonna have to elaborate on that because I have no idea what that means or how to apply that to my mask image view.

Comment: @matt so If I turn the (white) background of my mask image transparent, it will work? The only reason I assumed I needed black and white because some bloggers implicitly stated masks are always black and white. Cant find the link right now, though.

Comment: @matt Calm down, you only said it once and that was after I told you to explain what you mean by "opaque and transparent", which was your first comment. If you're gonna answer someone's question, you should at least try to do some explaining of the answer that you're giving, because the fact that I posted my question here should have been a hint that I am not a graphic designer or a freakin' scientist, so my sincere apologies for not being able to decrypt the three words you gave me into full-written instructions. Have a morning decaf, dude, you obviously need it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use a png image, which supports transparency, unlike jpg.

In Photoshop your image should look similar to this:

[image]

It doesn't matter if your shape is black or white. What matters is transparency of each pixel. Opaque area (black in this case) will be visible and transparent area will get trimmed.

**Edit:**

You should not create mask view from storyboard if you do so. It is not going to be a part of your view hierarchy. Just add it programmatically like this:

```
let maskView = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    maskView.image = UIImage(named: "mask")
    imageView.mask = maskView        
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    maskView.frame = imageView.bounds
}
```

Output:

[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j38zkp2filfjife/ImageMask.zip?dl=0) is a test project to show how it's working.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. I remember this is the first thing I tried, but then the exact opposite of the mask image (so the transparent part) ended up becoming the mask shape. Must have done something wrong there. I'll give it another shot. Thanks!

Comment: It's not working. I used the PNG image with a transparent, made both image views the exact same size, both width and height, but when I assign the mask image view as the mask of my default image view, they both disappear and the the view is just white, with nothing to be seen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I double checked to make sure the background is completely transparent, and to make sure the shape is completely opaque, but still nothing.

Comment: Ok, edit your question with some code to show how mask imageView is created and how it's frame is set.

Comment: I didn't set any frames programmatically. The only code I used is already in my question. I'm only assigning my mask image view to the mask property, that's it. From your reply, I can guess I forgot to do a bunch of stuff, right?

Comment: Try to create mask programmatically. It should not be added as a subview, as you did

Comment: That's impossible for me to do. Even a simple star or triangle is very difficult, since I've never drawn anything programmatically. Even worse is that the shapes I have are very complicated and detailed and are probably impossible to draw for ANYONE, let alone me. I don't get it, first you said I just need a opaque/transparent image and now you're telling me I shouldn't add it as a subview. So is it possible or not, because right now I'm way more confused than I was before asking this question.

Comment: First, you don't need to create shape programmatically, just create imageView with your png, as I posted yesterday in edited answer. Second, you should not add it as a subview (neither programmatically nor from xib/storyboard), all you need is to set `maskView` to `mask` property of `defaultImageView`

Comment: Oh okay, so should I configure anything else to the mask image view, like size for example, or just add it as the mask the way it is?

Comment: Just updated my post with some sample of my first (failed) attempt to set the mask programmatically. Any feedback?

Comment: @FreddyBenson Have you actually tried the code I suggested?

Comment: Yes, the image view completely disappears if I do that.

Comment: @FreddyBenson Try once again, I've updated the code sample. This time I've tested it myself and include a working project to make sure it is working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! I did everything exactly the way you did it in the test project, but it's still not working, so my best guess is that the image I'm using probably isn't correctly formatted. I'll try it out with a few other PNG images and see if that works. Anyway, thanks for the time and effort you put into making the project. Appreciate it!

Comment: How i create/draw a border around the masked image/ UIView?

Answer (score 3):

Also if you're using a custom frame/image and run into the mask not showing properly, try setting the content mode of the mask:

```
maskView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```